# SQL Change WHERE column and value depending on incoming variable

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have a stored procedure to filter results of a table based on incoming filter type and filter value.

At the moment this is in a very large If/Else statement:

```
IF @FilterBy = 'CustomerName'
  SELECT X, Y, Z
  FROM @Table
  WHERE CustomerName = @FilterValue
  ORDER BY CustomerID

ELSE IF @FilterBy = 'OrderID'
  SELECT X, Y, Z
  FROM @Table
  WHERE OrderID = CAST(@FilterValue AS SMALLINT)
  ORDER BY CustomerID
```

I've got 5 more Else Ifs and I'm always selecting the same columns from the same table. Is there a way to use something like the CASE or switch statement for the WHERE clause in order to clean up the code?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR instead of such if (or case) constructions.

Comment: Dynamic SQL might be the best approach.  This will force the query to be re-compiled, which is will ensure the best execution plan regardless of the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Like building a string up for the WHERE part and then appending it to the SELECT and executing?

Comment: I'd suggest changing your calling convention, if possible. Rather than an overloaded pair of parameters, can you not use one parameter per filter  (e.g. `@CustomerName` and `@OrderID`) and just use `NULL` to represent "do not filter on this value"? This would also obviously immediately allow you to support filtering by multiple columns.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever adding the extra parameters seems to be the best approach, extra functionality and gives especially with more conditions that could come in in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like the below query,

```
  SELECT X, Y, Z
  FROM @Table
  WHERE CustomerName    = (CASE WHEN @FilterBy = 'CustomerName' 
                                THEN @FilterValue ELSE CustomerName END)
    AND OrderID         = (CASE WHEN @FilterBy = 'OrderID' 
                                THEN  CAST(@FilterValue AS SMALLINT)    ELSE OrderID END)
  ORDER BY CustomerID
```

Comment: The second variant should work okay, but the first variant suffers the same issues I'm pointing to on etsa's answer - there's no guarantee of order of evaluation of predicates and no guarantee of short circuiting, so it  can easily raise errors by attempting to convert non-orderIDs to `smallint`. The `CASE` *should* offer protection here, provided no aggregates are involved in the query.

Answer (score 1):

Do you think could be useful for you?

```
SELECT X, Y, Z
  FROM @Table
  WHERE CustomerName = @FilterValue AND @FilterBy = 'CustomerName'
        OR 
        OrderID = CAST(@FilterValue AS SMALLINT) AND @FilterBy = 'OrderID'
        OR
        ...
  ORDER BY CustomerID
```

Comment: Unlikely to work out well - there's no guarantee on the execution order of predicates within a query, and so the system could easily decide to try to convert `'Mr Smith'` to a `smallint` even though `@FilterBy` is set to `CustomerName` and generate an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use CASE Statement in WHERE Clause to achieve your result easily :

 SELECT X, Y, Z FROM @Table
 WHERE CustomerName = CASE WHEN @FilterValue = 'CustomerName' THEN 
  @FilterValue ELSE CustomerName END AND 
  OrderID = CASE WHEN @FilterValue = 'OrderID' THEN CAST(@FilterValue AS         
  SMALLINT) ELSE OrderID END AND
  --- Your another 3 case statements like above format----
 ORDER BY CustomerID
```